# Linux VirtualBox on Windows10 - Right click opens up capture

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have been trying to get copy and paste working on virtualBox. I enabled the Mouse Integration to be able to see the mouse, but now when cliking right getting this window:

[image]

I have in the VirtualBox configuration the following:
Pointing Device: USB Tablet
[image]

Share Clipboard, drag'n drop bidirectional:
[image]

Installed the VBoxGuestAdditions:
[image]

I have also reinstalled Virtual Box with no luck.

Do you know what would be the issue to not being able to copy and paste in VirtualBox with Ubuntu 18.04?

Thanks

Comment: You're talking about a mouse click, yet you have VB set to Tablet… which is it?

Comment: it is when right click on touchpad in the laptop.

Comment: A touchpad isn't a tablet, it's a 'mouse'.

Comment: I tried with the other options as well with no luck. Not sure if the problem is that Ubuntu version is server instead of desktop.

Comment: I just finished the installation of Ubuntu desktop and it is working.